# How do I re-render a template in meteor, after calling a method, in an event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, meteor, render

In my rendered function a change some html on the page like so:

```
$($($('.round'+nextRound).find('li')[nextMatch]).find('.participant')[currentParticipant]).find('a').addClass('tooltip').html(winnerBox);
```

I need to undo that change in one of my event handlers aka:

```
'click #swear': function(event){
    Meteor.call('submitWinner', winnerInfo, thisCampaign._id, Meteor.user().apiKey, function(error, result) {
        // display the error to the user and abort
        if (error){
            return alert(error.reason);
        }else{
          !RE-RENDER MY TEMPLATE HERE!
          // Session.set('roundUpdated', true);
        }
    });
},
```

I've tried using session variables ect but am having absolutley no luck!
I think the problem is that this one template has 3 nested each blocks:

```
each round
  ul(class='round#{currentRound} of#{rounds}')
    each match
      li
       each participant
```

The helpers look like this:

```
round: function() {
    // Session.set('updated', (Session.get('updated')+1));
    var tournament = this.tournament.brackets;
    var rounds = tournament.length;
    var results = [];
    tournament.map(function(value, index){
        var currentRound = index + 1;
        results.push({rounds: rounds, currentRound: currentRound, matches: value});
    });
    // console.log("results:", results);
    return results;
},
match: function(){
    // console.log("matches:", this.matches);
    return this.matches;
},
participant: function(){
  // do some calculations here
  return results;
},
```

The code is a little incomplete for brevity, but hopefully you can get the idea!
The weirdest part is that if I put a log in the participant helper it logs the correct thing but it never get rendered back into the html... like it still has what I forced in with jquery.

If I update the template from another client then it works? like two seperate clients update correctly but one does not.

Any ideas of what's going on or what I can do to fix it?

Comment: If you wan't to "undo" the changes why don't you "undo" them rather then re-rendering the template?

Comment: because the actual data changes when i do the method call in the action.
aka I won't have access to the new data :/